# 2nd LED doesn't turn on as expected

Tags: relay, breadboard

I'm new to electronics and have been doing it as a hobby.

Today I tried to use a relay in my circuit to turn on and off 2 LED lights, as you can see in this schematic:

[image: schematic]

Image source: Make: Electronics by Charles Platt, 3rd edition

When I click the button, the 1st LED does go off - I see the relay connect to the other pole, but the 2nd LED doesn't turn off. I checked the connections and everything seems fine.

[image: breadboard]

[image: breadboard]

[image: breadboard]

Comment: please add a picture of the side view of the relay

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The common is in the middle of the set of contact connections, as you can see from the [datasheet](https://www.farnell.com/datasheets/1522527.pdf?_ga=2.236794817.1398409057.1693155933-2028378403.1689105244&_gac=1.89538281.1690379423.Cj0KCQjwiIOmBhDjARIsAP6YhSW_TZVyR5MCnFZ1A-Nb9VtoBYLke2u_reia3t2RSrA6W_y5Y5FnxSUaAr_9EALw_wcB) (or by looking inside the relay from the side).  You've got it connected like this:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I'm still not sure what's wrong, looking from the side it seems I made the proper connections:

https://ibb.co/0985dPj

:)

Comment: @pipocaDourada No, your photo proves otherwse - that the gray supply wire connects to the 3rd relay terminal and LED pins to middle and first terminal. Therefore middle and 3rd pins are connected by default and only the LED on midde pin lights up when you don't push the button. When you do push the button, the midde pin connects to leftmost pin and that means two LEDs are connected together and no LED receives supply from rightmost pin as it is disconnected.

Comment: Oh my! I see where my error is now, thank you so much it was driving me crazy!